# Delphi & Twebbrowser - How to recover a security token supplied by a login page?

Tags: security, delphi, twebbrowser

I am using the Twebbrowser in Delphi (2009) to log into cpanel on my ISP and add a new remote host IP address for a MySQL database. The user name and password are filled in by code as is clicking the submit button, using code gleaned from several places here.

Navigating directly to the hosts page causes the cpanel login page to be shown first. My program detects this and logs me in.

This uses a line like

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate'https://thedomain.sgcpanel.com:2083/cpsess1819495779/frontend/Crystal/sql/managehost.html');
```

which reaches the hosts page OK but I notice that the security token (cpsess1819495779) is changed to something else each time, presumably being supplied by the login page.

**However** if I try to login first as a separate operation and *then* navigate to the hosts page using

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate('https://thedomain.sgcpanel.com:2083');
```

followed by

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate'https://thedomain.sgcpanel.com:2083/cpsess1819495779/frontend/Crystal/sql/managehost.html');
```

I get a server message saying the url for the hosts page has an invalid security token - presumably the cpsess1819495779 bit

**Question**

How can I use Twebbrowser to get hold of the security token generated by the login page in order to use it to build the correct url for the hosts page so that I pass the correct security token each time.

It's probably something to do with cookies etc but I don't know how to deal with those (yet)

*BTW as the Twebbrowser is not visible I did spend quite a few days trying to do the same thing using Indy's TIdHTTP but have given up with that as am getting too many errors I can't sort out.*

Comment: If there is no API provided by the site and you want to _cheat_, capture the communication in a real browser and try to mimic the same using Indy or embedded browser. I would guess that the requests are POST instead of GET, but that's all just a wild guess without knowing the target site.

Comment: There is an API but it only seems to be accessible by php or perl running on a web site, not directly from Delphi. I also did try to use Fiddler and the Chrome HTTPSpy extension to see what was being sent and returned when logging in manually but couldn't see where the security token was - or else I couldn't understand what I was looking at. (I'm a technical programmer but so far have managed to stay well away from anything to do with web sites and HTTP syntax !

Comment: And if the person who down voted the question could please explain why they did it might help me, and others, to avoid making such an error again.

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted, but from my point of view it's impossible to help you with the current question wording (for those who don't know the site). Is that API described somewhere? Because that's the way to go (don't worry about possible examples in other languages). What you currently do with `Navigate` method without further parameters is a GET request; I believe that the site is expecting POST ones (but there can be far much more to resolve; API is the way to follow).

Answer (score 0):

I may as well answer this myself to close the question and maybe avoid any more down votes for posting a question after extensive research failed to produce the answer and that was framed without much of my code for brevity.

The API documentation for cpanel (the application used by many ISPs to manage MySQL, email etc) is here: https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/SDK/Guide+to+cPanel+API+2

part of that says

> **Security token**     After you log in to your server, it automatically appends a security token to the URL for your session. Security tokens
>   help prevent authorized use of a website through XSRF (Cross-Site
>   Request Forgery). Security tokens contain the string cpsess and a
>   10-digit number.

Logging in manually in IE / Chrome etc. does indeed show the token eg *cpsess1819495779* inserted into the original url that was navigated to. So if I navigate to

https://thedomain.sgcpanel.com:2083/cpsess0000000000/frontend/Crystal/sql/managehost.html

(to logon to cpanel), the part of the url displayed in the browser after cpsess gets changed to something like this, where the number changes each time.

https://secureukm11.sgcpanel.com:2083/cpsess1819495779/frontend/Crystal/sql/managehost.html

However, using Twebbrowser to show that modified url using

```
memo1.Lines.Add(WebBrowser1.LocationURL);
```

or

```
ShowMessage('URL: ' + Webbrowser1.OleObject.Document.Url);
```

simply shows the original url with the zeros, not the real security token.

So the answer to my question seems to be it can't be done in Twebbrowser as the url is only changed at the server and and the security token is not transmitted back to the browser.